# Unable to run ansible tasks on ESXi hosts

Tags: ansible, esxi

I am trying to run an ansible job targeting en ESXi host.

My playbook is simple. Setup a cronjob/Replace a cronjob.

I am 2 different approached ::

Approach 1 :

```
---
- hosts: esxi
  tasks:
   - name: Deploy cronjobs for CAC 2.0 nodes.
     cron: name="Deploy cronjobs" minute="1" hour="*" 
     job="/opt/test/test.sh" disabled=no
```

Approach 2 :

```
--- 
- 
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: esxi
  tasks: 
    - lineinfile: dest=/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root 
      regexp='^.*\/vmfs\/volumes\/datastore1\/scripts\/backup.sh$' 
      line='test'
```

When I run the playbook, both approaches fail stating:

```
fatal: [5.232.57.150]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, 
"module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call 
last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_GvDGZb/ansible_module_lineinfile.py\", line 
412, in <module>\r\n    from ansible.module_utils.basic import *\r\n  File 
\"/tmp/ansible_GvDGZb/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", 
line 52, in <module>\r\nImportError: No module named grp\r\n", "msg": 
"MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

Main ERROR ::

```
ImportError: No module named grp
```

In Debug mode :

```
fatal: [5.232.57.150]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, 
"invocation": {"module_name": "setup"}, "module_stderr": "OpenSSH_5.3p1, 
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013\ndebug1: Reading configuration data 
/etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: 
Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: 
mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3:         
mux_client_request_forwards: requesting forwardings: 0 local, 0 
remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3:         
mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done 
pid = 12018\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request 
sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug1: 
mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: 
mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received 
exit 
status from master 0\r\nShared connection to 5.232.57.150 closed.\r\n", 
"module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File 
\"/tmp/ansible_XhPWuX/ansible_module_setup.py\", line 123, in <module>\r\n    
from ansible.module_utils.basic import *\r\n  File 
\"/tmp/ansible_XhPWuX/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", 
line 
52, in <module>\r\nImportError: No module named grp\r\n", "msg": "MODULE 
FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

Would I need to install some python packages on ESXi host ?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the Python `grp` module (at least) is missing on the ESXi host, based on that error.  If you can easily get the right python modules installed via the ansible `shell` or `pip` modules, that may fix this.

[This Serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/626066/79266) used the Ansible `raw` module to work around the lack of this Python module.

See also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/LZi1DxMb-W8) which indicates this module is present on at least some ESXi versions.